# Play video different time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display 4 different videos depending on time of day (right know I only have two), I tried this way but somehow its not working, can someone tell why or help me in another effective way?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var Today = new Date();
  var H = Today.getHours();
  if (H >= 5 && H < 12) {

    console.log("morning");

    document.getElementById("vid1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("vid2").style.display = "none";


  } else if (H >= 12 && H < 21) {


    console.log("evening");

    document.getElementById("vid2").style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("vid1").style.display = "none";


  } else {
    console.log("night");
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div>

  <video id="vid1" muted autoplay>
            <source src="video/goodmorning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        
          </video>

</div>

<div>

  <video id="vid2" controls>
                <source src="video/teste.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            
              </video>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what 'it doesnt work' means? is there an error, do neither of your console log statements run?

Comment: yes, the console log statments run, but all the videos in html show up on the browser at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is to directly change `src` on `<source>` tag and you could apply `muted`, `controls` and `autoplay` for it.

```js
let video = document.querySelector('video')
let source = document.querySelector('source')
setInterval(function () {
 var Today = new Date();
 var H = Today.getHours();

 if (H >= 5 && H < 12 ) {

  source.src='video/goodmorning.mp4'
  video.muted = true
  video.autoplay =true 
  video.controls = false;
     video.load()
   

 }
 else if (H >= 12  && H < 21) {
   video.muted = false 
   video.autoplay = false;
   video.controls = true
  video.load();
   source.src="video/teste.mp4"
   console.log("evening");
   console.log(source.src)
   
  }
 else {
   console.log("night");  
 }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<video id="vid1">
        <source src="video/goodmorning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
      </video> 


    <div>

        </div>
```

Comment: it only plays the video that its writen in the html ("goodmorning), while know it should play the "teste.mp4" because its evening time now

Comment: @martzie, weird, you could check it print out the right `src`,  maybe I doesn't use the `video.load();` to make it load agian. I updated the code, check to see if it works now.

Comment: It works now, if I want to add another video on "night" should I repeat this code : video.muted = false 
   video.autoplay = false;
   video.controls = true
  video.load();
   source.src="video/night.mp4"
   console.log("evening");
   console.log(source.src)

or change the true and false statments?

Comment: @martzie, you should use `video.autoplay`, `video.controls`, `video.muted` since you have to specify it, but you could remove the two `console` since it is just for test purpose. In term of if statement, you could use else if you only have 3 videos, but you could also specify condition. Hope this helps

Comment: it did help, thank you!

Comment: @martzie, no problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making two video elements instead you change the src of the video element depending on the time of day.

```html
<div>

  <video id="vid" controls>
                <source src="video/goodmorning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            
              </video>

</div>
```

And then in your js just set the src depending on your conditions. I have extracted out the function and set it to a variable. This way we can call the function when the page loads so the correct video plays, we then use the interval function to periodically check.

```js
const playVideo = function() {
  var Today = new Date();
  var H = Today.getHours();
  var videoElement = document.getElementById("vid");
  videoElement.muted = true;
  videoElement.autoplay = true;
  videoElement.controls = true;
  if (H >= 5 && H < 12) {
    // If morning video is already set, do nothing and return
    if (videoElement.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src === "video/goodmorning.mp4") {
       return
    }
    console.log("morning");

    videoElement.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src = "video/goodmorning.mp4"


  } else if (H >= 12 && H < 21) {
    // If evening video is already set, do nothing and return
    if (videoElement.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src === "video/teste.mp4") {
       return
    }

    console.log("evening");

    videoElement.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src = "video/teste.mp4"


  } else {
    console.log("night");
  }
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

// call playVideo when the page loads so the correct video starts
// set interval to check every 3000ms and update accordingly.
playVideo();
setInterval(playVideo, 3000)
```

This way you do not need to worry about both of them playing, or having to hide one.

I have also added a check to see if the current video for that particular time is already correct. As you have this set to run every 3000 ms it will be constantly updating. If you wanted that to happen then omit the conditionals i added

Comment: it only plays the video that its writen in the html ("goodmorning), while know it should play the "teste.mp4" because its evening time now

Comment: I have added the video.load and video.play. However, because you have it on a setInterval this will update every 3000 ms. I would suggest you do this operation at page load and not worry about changing the video for a certain time of day by `setInterval`

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the issues i raised in the above comment

Comment: it still only displays the "goodmorning.mp4" it doesnt change throught the day